# if condition php reports generation

Tags: php

I created a Reports module in a medication administration webapp.
A medication can be stopped, and when it happens, it's value in the database turns to 1 (1=stopped 0=active). I need the report to show "STOPED" in the "administered by" column instead of the administrator's name when a medication is stopped so here is my code, but it's not working :( It returns "STOPED" for everything. What am I doing wrong ?
Any help will be appreciated!

```
 for (var i = 0; i < medi.length; i++) {

    keys_str += "<tr>";
    keys_str += "<td>" + medi[i].date + "</td>";
    if (medi[i].isprn == 'y' || medi[i].isprn == "Y")
        keys_str += "<td>PRN</td>";
    else
        keys_str += "<td>" + medi[i].time + "</td>";
    keys_str += "<td>" + medi[i].medicationame + "</td>";
    keys_str += "<td>" + medi[i].dosage + "</td>";
    if (medi[i].is_stop !== '1' || medi[i].is_stop !== "1")
        keys_str += "<td>STOPED</td>";
    else
        keys_str += "<td>" + medi[i].administeredby + "</td>";
    keys_str += "<td>" + medi[i].witness + "</td>";
    keys_str += "<td>" + medi[i].notes + "</td>";
    keys_str += "<td >  <img width='150px'   src='" + medi[i].e_sign + "' /></td>";

    keys_str += "</tr>";


}
$("#medication_hid_pdf").html();
$("#medication_hid_pdf").html(keys_str);

var date;
var time;
var medicationame;
var dosage;
var addministered;
var witness;
var str = "";
var count = 0;
for (property in medi) {
    if (medi.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        str += "<tr class='gradeX'>";
        date = medi[count].date;
        time = medi[count].time;
        medicationame = medi[count].medicationame;
        dosage = medi[count].dosage;
        addministered = medi[count].administeredby;
        witness = medi[count].witness;
        mid = medi[count].id;
        str += "<td>" + date + "</td>";
        if (medi[count].isprn == 'y' || medi[count].isprn == "Y")
            str += "<td>PRN</td>";
        else
            str += "<td>" + time + "</td>";
        str += "<td>" + medicationame + "</td>";

        str += "<td>" + dosage + "</td>";
        if (medi[count].is_stop !== '1' || medi[count].is_stop !== "1")
            str += "<td>STOPED</td>";
        str += "<td>" + addministered + "</td>";
        str += "<td>" + witness + "</td>";
        str += "<td>" + medi[count].notes + " </td>";
        str += "<td ><img width='150px'    src='" + medi[count].e_sign + "' /> </td>";
        str += "</tr>";
        count++;
    }
}


$("#medicationreport_data").html(str);

}

});
```

Comment: Why `1` usually `0` is bad `1` is good....

Comment: It's irrelevant really ....because active=0 is the starting status ...then switching it to stopped change it to the next value =1 ... but i guess t's irrelevant

Comment: Regardless you should use `parseInt` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt  just be sure to check for `NaN`  Or better yet cast it to an int before sending it to the Js side `(int)$var` or `intval($var)`, In other words you should do your best to "normalize" this data in PHP, it will make the job way easier in Javascript.  I would also suggest using an `associative` array or an Object in Js, instead of numbered indexes.

Comment: Just call me curious - but which part of this incomplete code sample is PHP?

Comment: The part where the tag on the question says `php` and the part where the OP says this, `it's value in the database turns to 1 (1=stopped 0=active)` so one must assume the Data comes from a database on the server.  Therefore a lot of this "mess" could be avoided by simply formatting the data correctly.  A lot of times people make way more work for themselves then they need to because they don't know how, or didn't take the time to structure the data properly.

Comment: If code is a house then the data model is the foundation, if it's weak, you have to shore it up by coding way more then you need to, and at some point the whole mess will come crumbling down...  There are a ton, of minor errors in this ( structurally ) that give me that opinion.  An example  is instead of all this "mess" `keys_str +=` it could be done by building an array and then using `'<td>'+array.join('</td><td>')+'</td>'`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what your error is, but there is a lot of minor "issues" and messyness.

Now as this question is tagged `PHP` and you mention getting the data from the `database` I will assume that there is some PHP file giving this data to Javascript.  How that is happening I cant tell by what is posted.

But my point is, that you should format as much of this data as you can on the PHP ( backend ) side of things.  Most of this is stuff like:

```
....
if (medi[count].isprn == 'y' || medi[count].isprn == "Y")
    str += "<td>PRN</td>";
else
    str += "<td>" + time + "</td>";
....
if (medi[i].is_stop !== '1' || medi[i].is_stop !== "1")
    keys_str += "<td>STOPED</td>";
else
    keys_str += "<td>" + medi[i].administeredby + "</td>";
......
```

Basically we are just checking a value and changing it, so here PHP's `loosly` typed nature will help you more then JavaScripts `weakly` typed.

In PHP this would be something like this

```
$formatted = []; 
foreach( $medi as $row ){ 
   $data = [];  //create a clean array if you have to

   $data['isprn'] = strtolower($row['isprn']) == 'y' ? 'PRN' : $row['time'];

   $data['is_stop'] = $row['is_stop'] != '1' ? 'STOPED' : '';

   //include other stuff in $data you need

   $formatted[] = $row;
}
```

Then if you get it clean enough, in Javascript you can do stuff like this

```
 var str = '';
 for (var i = 0; i < medi.length; i++) {
    str += '<tr>';
    str += '<td>' + medi[i].join('</td><td>') + '</td>';
    str += '</tr>';
 }
```

There are many many ways to do this, and there is a lot of "necessary" information missing for me to really be able to do much more.  But I would "Strongly" suggest, `normalizing` all this data on the server side as best as can be done.  Then on the client side you will really reduce the amount of work needed to display it to the end user.